# React Router - Nested Routes for Notebook and Note Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to create a `Notebook` application where I have a list of notebooks such as "Mathematics" and "Science". When I select one of the notebooks, I want to display a list of notes within that selected notebook. Then, when I click on a specific note, I want to open that note and display its content in a separate component, where I can either continue taking notes or edit the existing note.

I have created separate `NotebookList`, `Notebook`, and `Note` components for this project.

I'm currently using React Router and I'm having trouble configuring the component and route structure to achieve this functionality.

Here's what I have so far:

NotebookList.js

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const NotebookList = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Notebooks</h1>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/notebook/mathematics">Mathematics</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/notebook/science">Science</Link></li>
        {/* Add more notebook options here */}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NotebookList;
```

Notebook.js

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const Notebook = () => {
  const { notebookId } = useParams();

  // Fetch the notes for the selected notebook using notebookId

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Notebook: {notebookId}</h1>
      {/* Display the list of notes */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Notebook;
```

Note.js

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const Note = () => {
  const { notebookId, noteId } = useParams();

  // Fetch the content of the selected note using notebookId and noteId

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Note: {noteId}</h1>
      {/* Display the content of the note */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Note;
```

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import NotebookList from './NotebookList';
import Notebook from './Notebook';
import Note from './Note';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route exact path="/" component={NotebookList} />
      <Route path="/notebook/:notebookId" component={Notebook} />
      <Route path="/notebook/:notebookId/note/:noteId" component={Note} />
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I would appreciate any guidance on how to properly configure the component and route structure to achieve the desired functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';    
import NotebookList from './NotebookList';    
import Notebook from './Notebook';    
import Note from './Note';    

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route exact path="/" component={NotebookList} />
      <Route path="/notebooks">
          <Route path="notebook/:notebookId" component={Notebook} />
          <Route path="notebook/:notebookId/note/:noteId" component={Note} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Try this here your url will be "localhost:3000/notebooks/notebook/{anyid}" for the the Notebook component

Comment: Actually, I have an idea that a bigger app that includes a note app as one of its modules, so I want to keep the "/" route to the "dashboard" component.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The `Router` component ***inclusively*** renders all matches to the current URL path. If you want the components to render separately on their own then render the routes into the `Switch` component. Keep in mind that within the `Switch` that path order and specificity matters. Order the routed in the inverse order of path specificity, e.g. *more* specific paths before *less* specific paths. This eliminates the need to use the `exact` prop in almost 100% of the use cases.

Example:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/notebook/:notebookId/note/:noteId" component={Note} />
        <Route path="/notebook/:notebookId" component={Notebook} />
        <Route path="/" component={NotebookList} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```